# How to emulate Google cloud tasks service locally in app engine flex (Python 3.7)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

I have been using **Google App Engine Standard Environment(Python 2.7)** since some days now. It provides a good local development server, providing Task queues, datastore and other services locally.

Recently i have been exploring **App Engine Flex Environment (Python 3.7)** for some of the projects. Within that i am trying use various services like Cloud Tasks, GCS, Pubsub etc. Some of the services like pubsub has an emulator to run it locally. I couldn't find such emulator for cloud tasks.

Is there any way to emulate/simulate Cloud Tasks locally?

Answer (score 6):

I just built an [emulator](https://github.com/aertje/cloud-tasks-emulator), see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, local server emulator is not available for App Engine Flex Environment (Python 3.7) [1] However you can use Cloud Pub/Sub in some cases as workaround [2].

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/migrating#features_in_task_queues_not_yet_available_via

[2] https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-pub-sub

Answer (score 0):

I built an  [in-process emulator](https://github.com/doitintl/Cloud-Tasks-In-Process-Emulator) for Python development.

See also some emulators that run in a separate process in localhost:  Potato London’s [gcloud-tasks-emulator](https://pypi.org/project/gcloud-tasks-emulator/) and Aert van de Hulsbeek’s [cloud-tasks-emulator](https://github.com/aertje/cloud-tasks-emulator), mentioned in the answer above.